# How to use StringEdit control as search in Axapta?

Tags: axapta

In the `Purchtable` form I have a `StringEdit` control.

When I type a `PurchId` in the `StringEdit` control, it should act as a search and should retrieve the current PurchId in the Grid.

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a modified method to the controls method node:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    ;
    SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(purchTable_ds.queryRun().query().dataSourceNo(1), fieldNum(PurchTable,PurchId)).value(this.text());
    purchTable_ds.research();
    return ret;
}
```

This will add a `PurchId` query range to the `PurchTable` data source, fill it with your entered value, then do a research on the data source.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept Jan's answer, there's only a minor correction I want to add - I don't think it'll work with `research`, should be `executeQuery` instead:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    Query q;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    QueryBuildRange qbr;
    boolean ret;
    ;

    ret = super();

    q = purchTable_ds.queryRun().query();
    qbds = q.dataSourceTable(tablenum(PurchTable));
    qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(PurchTable,PurchId));
    qbr.value(this.text());
    PurchTable_ds.executeQuery();

    return ret;
}
```

Test it, anyway.